# how to refer to the former?

Tags: gramática

In the following sentence

> Cuando era aprendiz asistía un día a una conversación entre su maestro
> y un parroquiano, en la cual **éste** mantenía que todos los hombres eran
> iguales.

**éste** seems to refer to "the latter". Can I say

> Cuando era aprendiz asistía un día a una conversación entre su maestro
> y un parroquiano, en la cual **esa** mantenía que todos los hombres eran
> iguales.

i.e. to use **esa** to refer "the former"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cuando era aprendiz asistía un día (...)

The verb "*asistir*" should be in [simple past tense](https://www.spanishdict.com/conjugate/asistir): "*asistió*".
In this case, using *imperfect past tense* would be similar to saying: "*One day, when he/she was an apprentice, he/she **used to attend** a conversation...*", instead of: "*One day, when he/she was an apprentice, he/she **attended** a conversation...*"

Also, a comma is missing between the adverbial syntagma and the next syntagma. It should be written like this:
"*Cuando era aprendiz, asistió un día...*"

> en la cual esa mantenía...

Here, you can't use "*esa*" because of two reasons.
First: "maestro" and "parroquiano" are in masculine gender, and "esa" is in feminine gender.
Second: if you're referencing *el parroquiano*, this part of the sentence should be like this:
"*en la cual **este último** mantenía...*"
And if you're referencing *su maestro*:
"*en la cual **el primero** mantenía...*"
Following the order in which both of them are mentioned.
Because they are mentioned together, writing "*aquél*", "*ese*" or "*él*" would be unspecific despite being in singular form.

Comment: Thank you! So in the original, was "en la cual **éste** mantenía" correctly used if trying to say **este último**?

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there but in fact the former is aquél or one of its forms. Spanish uses the maximum contrast here between this one (the latter, nearest to me) and the one over there (the former, possibly a long way away).

Comment: Ah, so this will be grammatically and semantically correct? `Cuando era aprendiz asistía un día a una conversación entre su maestro y un parroquiano, en la cual aquel mantenía que todos los hombres eran iguales.`